# Android: Hide button from another activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, editor, sharedpreferences

I have 2 activities. Initially the button in first activity is invisible. What I want is that when I click a button in the second activity then the button in my first activity should become visible.

This is my second activity code till now.

```
this.promodeimage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ///What should i do in here 
     }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Do one thing ! its easy .. just make the button in your first activity as public static**

```
public class Activity_One extends Activity {

public static Button btnOne ;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_one);


       btnOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOne);
}
```

Now all you need to do is that from Second Activity just **access it using the class name of the first activity i.e  Activity_One.btnOne**

```
public class Activity_Two extends Activity {

     Button btnTwo ;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_one);


           btnTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTwo);

btnTwo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Activity_One.btnOne.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
```

Let me know if this works for you ! :)

Comment: Why are u posting the same answer as me, but half an hour later?

Comment: It's not good relying on static variables in Android I think.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem make your button **static** in your **first** activity like:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity { 

public static Button yourButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);

        yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourButtonId);
    }
}
```

this way u can get to the button in ur **second** activity like this:

```
FirstActivity.yourButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);    //Make it invisible
FirstActivity.yourButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //Make it visible
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score -1):

In your First Activity, check in the onCreate() using

```
if(getIntent().getExtras().getString("modepro").equals("yes")){

    yourButton.setVisibilty(View.VISIBLE)
}
```

Comment: please check my question  tell me the code what is write onclicklistener in modeactivity

Answer (score -2):

You can use something like this whenever you need to implement your logic.

```
 yourButton.setEnabled(true)--->Here is enabled.
 yourButton.setEnabled(false)---> Here is disabled.
```

Good Luck.!