# How can I set a button to invisible from one activity to another?

Tags: android

I am a android developer beginner, and I need some help please.
I have one activity (activity 1) with a button named "MORE", which when clicked takes me to another activity. This works well.
And I have another activity (activity 2). When I click on one checkbox, I need to make the button "MORE" invisible in the activity 1. 
I found other similar questions, but it is throwing an error and I couldn't figure it out.

I made the button static in the activity 1

```
public static Button btn2;
```

In the activity 2 I set it to invisible

```
public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent i;

        switch (view.getId()) {

            case R.id.checkBox2:
                // set invisible button more in stock quotes
                StockDetail.btn2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                break;

            default:
                break;

    }
}
```

It is throwing this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button

I found a similar question in this link:
[Android: Hide button from another activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35455874/android-hide-button-from-another-activity)
I did exactly like that, but it still does not. I appreciate if someone can help me. Thank you

Comment: Please interfaces to achieve this. Don't go for static variables with View class.

Comment: Instead of taking static button, take one static int or boolean variable in activity 1 and then on check change the value of that variable and in activity 1, onResume() method check the variable value and set visibility accordingly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - to control the button from another activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978245/android-to-control-the-button-from-another-activity)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should save a variable such as isShow (boolean) by SharePreference file. When you open activity1, you will get value at the sharepreference file.
Such as: If it is true --> you will set visible for button.

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT make any variable static that may use `context` (like your button) as it may be highly susceptible to memory leaks. Usually there are various design patterns in place to avoid these.

A simple solution for your case can be starting your `Activity2` from `Activity1` using `startActvityForResult()`. In this setup the `Activity1` expects some kind of result from `Activity2`. In your case it would be the state of your button. To learn more about it visit this [very small] official training doc: [Getting a Result from an Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html).

Let us know if you tun intoo any issues.

Answer (score 0):

you can apply a null point check like this

```
if(StockDetails.btn2 != null)
 {
  StockDetails.btn2.setVisiblity(View.Gone);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not work until StockDetail will be created. Alternatively for that you can do make a static variable inside StockDetail class like below:-

```
public class StockDetail extends Activity{
 public static int buttonVisibility=View.VISIBLE;

@override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  setContentView(R.layout.act2);
  Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
  btn.setVisibilty(buttonVisibility);

}
```

and from Activity1

```
public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent i;

        switch (view.getId()) {

            case R.id.checkBox2:
                // set invisible button more in stock quotes
                StockDetail.buttonVisibility=View.INVISIBLE;
                break;

            default:
                break;

    }
}
```

try the above it may help you.

Comment: @Felipe Glad to know it help you out.Please accept and upvote the answer so that it can be helpful for others too. Thanks in advance. :)